# Print file name in quotation marks using cat and sprintf

Tags: r

I have a vector containing filenames and I would need to write exactly the following string on a file, containing the following path in quotation marks and being able to enter the i-th file name as well. I would like to get (in quotation marks):

```
"C:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\001.dat"
```

being `files[i] <- "001.dat"` therefore I tried:

```
sprintf(cat('"',"c:\\Users\\Enrico\\Tesi\\Paullo\\TIMESERIES\\%s", '"', sep=""), files[i])
```

but I can't insert the string correctly and I get:

```
"C:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\%s"
```

Can anyone help me to concatenate cat and sprintf? thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sprintf` should look like this:

```
sprintf("\"c:\\Users\\Enrico\\Tesi\\Paullo\\TIMESERIES\\%03d.dat\"", i)
```

The `cat` should be outside the `sprintf`, and if you want to print the files on separate lines, you could add a line break (`"\n"`). So in a loop, we could do:

```r
for(i in 1:10) {
  cat(sprintf("\"c:\\Users\\Enrico\\Tesi\\Paullo\\TIMESERIES\\%03d.dat\"", i), "\n")
}
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\001.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\002.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\003.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\004.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\005.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\006.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\007.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\008.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\009.dat" 
#> "c:\Users\Enrico\Tesi\Paullo\TIMESERIES\010.dat"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly! I ask you a little thing though, I should insert this string in a tibble like: `my.tibble <- tibble (Name = "FILE", File = cat(sprintf("\"c:\\Users\\Enrico\\Tesi\\Paullo\\TIMESERIES\\%03d.dat\"", i))` but it doesn't work, do I have to insert the string into a vector? Thank you so much and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @EnricoLochi you can add the `sprintf` without the `cat`

Comment: You're right! I hadn't thought of that, I'm right at the beginning with R .. thanks again!